# Java sql insert JOptionpane

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Trying to insert a single row into a database in Java. It only inserts first column and I have no idea why. Here is the code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    int x = 1;
    int limit;
    //promts the user to enter input
    //  String InputString = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the Number of Countries: ",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
    // limit = Integer.parseInt(InputString);  

    Connection connection;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    try {
        String dbName = "osdesign";
        String dbUserName = "root";
        String dbPassword = "";
        //String u = jtfuser.getText();
        //String p =jpfpass.getName();
        String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/" + dbName + "?user="
                + dbUserName + "&password=" + dbPassword
                + "&useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionString);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected!");

        //int x = 1;
        User List = new User();

        //User[] List = new User [limit];
        //String query;
        //for (x = 0; x < limit; x++)
        // {
        ///List[x] = new User();  
        //List[x].User_type = null;
        List.input(x);
        //String sql = "INSERT into `userlist` (`UsrCode`, `UsrName`, `UsrPass`, `UsrPassChgDays`, `UsrPassChgDate`, `Usrtype`) VALUES( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?);";

        PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `userlist`" + 
                "VALUES( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?);");

        String ID = List.ID;
        String name = List.name;
        preparedStmt.setString(1, ID);
        preparedStmt.setString(2, name);
        preparedStmt.setString(3, List.password);

        preparedStmt.setString(4, List.Usr_PassChgDays);
        preparedStmt.setString(5, List.data_of_passChg);
        preparedStmt.setString(6, List.User_type);

        preparedStmt.executeUpdate();
        //btnlogin.equals(result);
        // panel.add(btnlogin);
        //   panel.add(jpfpass.getName(),btnlogin);
        if (preparedStmt.equals(true)) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Great sucess!!!");
            //this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "FUCK!!!");
        }

        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "User sucessfully created");
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(RychlikSystemversion0.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Looked everywhere on the internet and tried every trick and I am honestly puzzled. Can someone help me please?

Comment: You have to make sure that the data types in Java matches the data types of columns in the database. e.g. `preparedStmt.setString(1, ID);` should be `preparedStmt.setInt(1, ID);`!!

Comment: I changed the database value to varchar and it still is giving me issues. The program swears at you so it is not inserting the row.

Comment: I initially had the same thought as @Kh.Taheri. Was your ID column **within** the database table a String data type or a Integer data type and exactly what is it now? Does **List** actually contain anything? Test for that. Put it out to console: `System.out.println(List.ID); System.out.println(List.name); System.out.println(List.password);` etc.

Comment: Still does the same thing and just prints out ID. It inserts data into just the primary key which is really odd. I know it connects to Database because I have a login swing frame that works just fine.

Comment: You never set any values on `List` that we can see. As I commented on your other question, you really need to debug to see if you actually have the values you expect. In this case, you could also first try to use explicit literal values in the `setString` methods for values 2 - 6 to see if the problem is actually with your database code, or with the `User` class (which as far as we can see you did nothing to initialize, except maybe setting its id, so likely all fields are still `null`). Otherwise post an MCVE with all relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Please edit SQL query remove ; end query

```
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO `userlist`" + 
                "VALUES( ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  ?)**;**");
```

Comment: Why? Does MySQL not like it? I thought all database systems accept SQL statements with the semicolon at the end. After all, it's the standard way to separate each SQL statement in database systems that allow more than one SQL statement to be executed in the same call to the server. For some database systems it's a downright necessity. Some systems don't require it and T-SQL might not require it right now...but it will soon.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Not necessarily, in some database systems it is only a separator in the client, not on the server itself (so a CLI knows when the statement is complete and can be sent to the server for execution). Though given the information in the question, I agree this probably is not the cause.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel - In some. As I had stated in my previous comment: "Some systems don't require it..."

Comment: @DevilsHnd IIRC, the MySQL Connector/J disallows `;` if you haven't set it to allow multiple statements to be executed at once (the JDBC expectation is one statement per execute).